# wx Python: Invisible/Transparent Dialog

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a wx.Dialog with a wx.Grid that is contained within a ScrolledWindow panel. The dialog is launched by a menu item on the main frame that is not the dialog's parent.

Occasionally, when my dialog launches the content within this panel is not visible! As shown:
[image]

The print statements I have during the creation of GUI components are being executed so I'm not sure why occasionally there is no content within the Dialog?

When this starts happening, I close and relaunch the dialog, however it often happens multiple times in a row and then seemingly resolves itself, displaying normally on the 5th+ try.

Has anyone else encountered this? What was the cause?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and wx.Python 3.0

Edit: including the code sample where I think the problem could lie.

I have a 'redraw' method which is called to calculate the size of the Dialog because of the ScrolledWindow. There are buttons next to each row of the wx.Grid so I cannot allow the wx.Grid to handle it's own scrolling. This method is called after the addition of a new row to the wx.Grid.

The redraw method is as follows:

```
def redraw(self):
    # a change has been made to the file, reset saved boolean
    self.m_saved_or_cancelled = False
    # call these to update the view
    self.m_list_view.AutoSize() # this is the wx.Grid 
    self.m_list_view.Fit()
    self.scrolled_panel.Layout()
    self.Layout()
    self.Fit()

    # as we have a scrolledWindow panel - we must update the minimum size in order to display the view
    # the maximum size is the display size
    display_width, display_height = wx.DisplaySize()

    w, sizer_height = self.main_sizer.GetSize()

    # height of the rows
    button_height = 10
    # number of items
    items = self.m_list_view.GetNumberRows() + 1
    cols =  self.m_list_view.GetNumberCols()

    # column widths added together
    col_width = 100
    for col in range(cols):
        col_width += self.m_list_view.GetColSize(col)

    print "col_width %s" % col_width

    # height is at least the minimum or the row height * number of items
    height = button_height * items
    print "sizer_height %s, height %s" % (sizer_height, height)

    if height < self.MIN_WINDOW_HEIGHT:
        height = self.MIN_WINDOW_HEIGHT

    print "sizer_heighth %s, height %s" % (sizer_height, height)

    if height <= sizer_height:
        # increase by a factor of this space 2/3
        height += ((sizer_height)/3)
    print "height %s" % height

    if height > (display_height - self.MAX_WINDOW_HEIGHT_OFFSET):
        self.SetMinSize((col_width, display_height - self.MAX_WINDOW_HEIGHT_OFFSET))
        self.SetSize((col_width, display_height - self.MAX_WINDOW_HEIGHT_OFFSET))
    else:
        self.SetMinSize((col_width, height))
        self.SetSize((col_width, height))

    # the virtual size has to be greater than required space rather significantly in order to display correctly
    self.scrolled_panel.SetVirtualSize((col_width, height))
    self.scrolled_panel.AdjustScrollbars()
    self.scrolled_panel.Layout()
    # centered
    self.CenterOnScreen()
```

Comment: Can you show **minimal** code that exposes that behaviour?

Comment: @Ripi2  As it doesn't replicate consistently, I have been struggling to come up with a small code sample that displays this behaviour. I will continue to try to make one and post it tomorrow.

Comment: It looks like the dialog might have 0 size, can you try resizing it, from keyboard if you can't do it using the mouse to check if this is the case?

Comment: @VZ. I have updated the question to include a code sample. I don't think the size is 0 as it is calculated and set in the method I've included in the code sample. Thank you for the suggestion. How do you resize it from the keyboard? Within the code?

Comment: if you resize the dialog will everything show up?

Comment: @user2682863 clicking the maximise icon or dragging the corners has no effect :(

Comment: can you post a minimal working example?